# C - If (No File Found) { Use standard input }

Tags: c, file, input, stdin

I have a program that reads from a file, but if there is no file declared in the arguments array, then I would like to read from stdin in the terminal eg:

```
 ./program.out test.txt
```

reads from test.txt

```
 ./program.out
```

reads from stdin:

here's my code for some context:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fr;
char *line;
char *word;
size_t len =256;
int i=0;
int sum=0;
char *vali;
const char delim = ' ';
int flag=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

line = (char *)malloc(len);
word = (char *)malloc(len);


/*
line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
vali = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
*/
    fr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fr==NULL){
        //fr="/dev/stdin"; <-- Piece of code I need for this stackoverflow question
    }

        while (getline(&line, &len, fr) != -1){
            /* printf("%s", line ); */
            if(strlen(line) != 1){
                sscanf(line,"%s%*[^\n]",word);
                 printf("%-10s ", word); 
                char *scores = line + strlen(word) + 1;         
    /*          printf("scores: %s", scores); */



                vali=strtok(scores, &delim);
                while(vali != NULL){
                    sum=sum+atoi(vali);

                    vali = strtok(NULL, &delim);
                }

                printf("%3d\n", sum);
                sum=0;
            }
        }
        fclose(fr);

    free(line);
//   free(word);
//  free(vali);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
fr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if(fr==NULL){
    //fr="/dev/stdin"; <-- Piece of code I need for this stackoverflow question
}
```

to

```
if ( argc > 1 )
{
    // A file was passed in as the first argument.
    // Try to open it.
    fr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(fr==NULL){
       // Deal with the error of not being able to open the file.
    }
}
else
{
    // Nothing was passed to the program.
    // use stdin.
    fr = stdin;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will accept as answer when I can in 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

How about just:

```
if(fr==NULL){
    fr=stdin;
```

They're both file pointers after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fr;
char *line;
char *word;
size_t len =256;
int i=0;
int sum=0;
```

These are already 0. 40$ fine.

```
char *vali;
```

Non-english variable name. 50$ fine.

```
const char delim = ' ';
int flag=0;
```

Using global variables for no reason is grounds for a fine up to 10$ per byte. Inconsistent spacing is additional 20$.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
```

Inconsistent placement of '*'.

```
line = (char *)malloc(len);
word = (char *)malloc(len);
```

Casting malloc is 50$. http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html

```
/*
line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
word = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
vali = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&len));
*/
```

Consider #if 0 ... #endif instead.

```
    fr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Inconsistent indentation.

It was not checked whether an argument was provided in the first place.

Standard behaviour is to open stdin if "-" is passed as the name.

```
    if(fr==NULL){
        //fr="/dev/stdin"; <-- Piece of code I need for this stackoverflow question
```

Incorrect on its principle. Falling back to stdin if the program failed to open passed file is a criminal offence, even more so given that there is no indication given.

You should check your arguments. If a file was provided and opening it failed, **print an error**.

Finally, there are plenty of unix commandline tools which default to stdin and have sources available out there (e.g. cat), so you could have just checked what they do. Interestingly enough, there is a FILE pointer called stdin which you can use here.

```
    }

        while (getline(&line, &len, fr) != -1){
```

Even more inconsistent indentation.

```
            /* printf("%s", line ); */
            if(strlen(line) != 1){
```

Why? Does not 'len' have it?

```
                sscanf(line,"%s%*[^\n]",word);
```

What? This really can be done much nicer. You know the newline has to be last and the length is known.

```
                 printf("%-10s ", word); 
                char *scores = line + strlen(word) + 1;         
    /*          printf("scores: %s", scores); */



                vali=strtok(scores, &delim);
                while(vali != NULL){
                    sum=sum+atoi(vali);

                    vali = strtok(NULL, &delim);
                }

                printf("%3d\n", sum);
                sum=0;
```

Not very good man. At least do sum = 0; just prior to modifying it in the loop. Just stray sum=0 makes one wonder what is going on here. 10$.

```
            }
        }
        fclose(fr);
```

Finally, if the thingy turns out to be stdin this should not be executed.

```
    free(line);
//   free(word);
//  free(vali);
```

Well, you allocate both word and line, but not vali so commented out part is incorrect.

```
    return 0;
}
```